# I can't get the label for an id in facebook

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to extract the label or title of an id, and I'm using facebook for experimenting it. I'm expecting the result to have 'Email or Phone' printed but I am not able to succeed in doing so.

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.facebook.com/'
#this is where chrome is stored in my computer
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver")

driver.get(url)

d = driver.find_element_by_id('email')

label = d.get_attribute('label')

print(label)
```

Comment: The label text for a form field is tricky. The form field can be nested inside a `<label>` or referenced by a label tag using the for attribute: `<label for="email">`. The form field could have the `aria-label` attribute on it, and it could have an `aria-labelledby` attribute on it. Can you post a snippet of the HTML you are dealing with?

Comment: FWIW: don't use FB as a test target; use a test site like www.example.org.

Comment: @GregBurghardt here you go https://imgur.com/R6x8fNo

Comment: That image is such a low resolution I can't see much of anything.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Might be device's fault chief. It's as clear as day to me

Comment: I'm on a desktop machine with a wide screen monitor. It appears the link you posted is to an image resized smaller than the original. Can you please update your question with the actual code rather than posting a link to a screenshot?

Comment: It's the source code of facebook.com